# Get count of reachable live objects

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I'm currently debugging a memory leak in a Python program.  Since none of my objects have a `__del__` method, I'm assuming the issue is some sort of global variable that continues to accumulate references to reachable objects.  Also, when I run using `gc.debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK)`, I see a lot of `gc: collectable` messages, but no `gc: uncollectable` messages.  To confirm this suspicion, I'd like to somehow get a count of the total number of reachable objects in my program, so I can confirm that it is steadily increasing.

Is there any way to get this?  I was looking at `gc.get_count` but this seems to give me the number of objects which were actually collected (separated by generation) rather than the number of live objects which are still reachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `gc.get_objects` is what you want. Be careful using `DEBUG_LEAK` as it implies `DEBUG_SAVEALL`. `DEDUG_SAVEALL` causes all unreferenced objects to be saved in `gc.garbage` rather than freed. This means the number of objects tracked by the garbage collector can only increase. Additionally `gc.get_objects` does not return all currently live objects, as some types are not tracked by the garbage collector (atomic types are not tracked). For instance, `[i for i in range(1000)]` will only increase the objects tracked by one as the integers are not tracked by the garbage collector. Whereas, `[[] for i in range(1000)]` will increase the number of objects tracked by 1001.